# CSS Sprite Image issues inside jquery-ui tab menu nav

Tags: css

I am currently having problems with icons i am placing inside my nav menu for the tabs. I used an online image css sprite creator and it worked well. The issue is now the picture are showing up incorrectly. How can i fix this issue? Here is my [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php) 
**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#tab-1" class="pngIcon sprite-category">1. Category</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-2" class="pngIcon sprite-description">2. Description</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-3" class="pngIcon sprite-images">3. Images</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-4" class="pngIcon sprite-contact">4. Contact Info</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-5" class="pngIcon sprite-final">5. Final</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS I got the coordinates from the website that made the css sprite image**

```
.sprite-final{  background-position: 0 0; width: 32px; height: 32px; } 
.sprite-category{ background-position: 0 -82px; width: 32px; height: 32px; } 
.sprite-contact{ background-position: 0 -164px; width: 32px; height: 32px; } 
.sprite-description{ background-position: 0 -246px; width: 32px; height: 32px; } 
.sprite-images{ background-position: 0 -328px; width: 32px; height: 32px; }


.pngIcon {
    padding: 0;
    background: url(http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/images/tabdetails.png) no-repeat top left;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-indent: 40px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display: block;
}
```

CSS Sprite Image

[image]

Comment: well css is case sensitive, so fix that capital F on sprite-final for a start. Edit: Can i just add you are using id and classes wrong, class is for something that is used more than once, in this case #pngIcon, whereas ID should be unique, in this case all the sprite-xx.

Comment: do you really need that <img> tag inside <a> tag? why don't you just use <a> tag and add classes with "background" property?

Comment: Also, in your code <img src="images/tabdetails.png" width="32" height="32" id="pngIcon" class="sprite-category" /> you first call whole image tabdetails.png with all icons, and then again class wiht same icon. All that in same img tag. And because of that, all icons are showed in the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sprites are meant for backgrounds only. remove the `img` tags for starters.
then add the `.sprite-Final, ...` classes directly to the `a` tags
also add a class `pngIcon` to each of the anchors (not as an #id, an id can only occur once per page!)
then update your css as follows:

```
.pngIcon {
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(images/tabdetails.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-indent: 40px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display: block;
}
```

I think that should do the trick...

Comment: +1 I have change it from id to a class accordingly to your suggestion. But by removing `img` do you mean setting it up like this `<li><a href="#tab-1" class="pngIcon sprite-category">1. Category</a></li>`

Comment: yep, that's exactly what i mean

Comment: Oh alright, I am not sure why but it is now repeating the same picture in all tabs. Please check the [CHANGES](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php) that were made.

Comment: try removing all 'width: 32px;' code from the .sprite classes and update the css as in my post, i made some changes...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check your IDs and classes. IDs are unique and shouldn't be repeated in the code, while classes are exactly for that: repeating. I'd change that before anything else.

Second, css is cascade styles, so it is important which style is read first. You are defining the classes, and after that you are giving the order `background: url(images/tabdetails.png) no-repeat top left;` to #pngIcon (top left is equivalent of `background-position`).

And third and **more important**, you should give the background to the `<a>`, instead of using images. Your css is not being applied!

Comment: thank you, I am not sure how i committed such crimes confusing classes with ids but I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your specific classes to the `<a>` element. Then you will apply the sprite as a background to each of those. You don't need the `<img>` element in there.

```
<li><a href="#tab-1" class="sprite-Final">1. Category</a></li>
```

Then give that anchor element some padding to the left side. Maybe something like 35px since the icons are 32 pixels wide. Doing this will push the text "1. Category" over to the right. Apply any adjustments to the anchor to make the text align nicely with the background icon image. The `line-height: X;` attribute is best to vertically align.